# How do you use a multiple leaf texture file on a sapling curve tree?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, sapling-addon

Textures.com offers leaf textures in a [multiple-leaf-per](https://www.textures.com/download/3datlas0162/133410?q=leaf) file format. There are also six files for all the maps.

Is the expectation that I open these in gimp and make them into separate images (somehow keeping the edits identical across all six images/maps), or is there a way to use a file like this directly in Blender where you draw bounds around the individual leaves and it assigns one of the groups randomly to each leaf instance? This is for a sapling generated tree in 2.81a.

[image]

Comment: You can select or deselect random faces in the Select Menu. Then you can edit them in the UV Editor at the same time. (You can select each overlapping verts with the border[Button B] or the brush[Button C] selection tool).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple objects can use different parts of the same material using UV mapping. In this example, The original UVs of the image plane are cut automatically when using the Knife tool. Split the edges and separate the loose parts to create multiple objects. Note the single material used.

That same material can also use the same UVs for applying alpha, normals etc...

Note: the "Import Image as Plane" is an Addon.

[image]